# Mysql left outer join retrieving wrong data from joined table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am just learning how to join tables in mysql.  Everything is working in my query, except that it is pulling the wrong Vendor Name from the vendor table.  I have tried several things to fix this but nothing is working.  All the other information returned is correct.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_pic, 
       AVG(r.review_stars), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.review_id), MIN(c.price_price), 
       p.product_url, v.vendor_name, p.product_clicks, 
       SUM(c.price_clicks), COUNT(c.price_price), 
       c.price_affiliate
  FROM products as p 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews as r ON p.product_id = r.review_product
  LEFT OUTER JOIN prices as c ON c.price_product = p.product_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vendors as v ON c.price_vendor = v.vendor_id
 GROUP BY p.product_id
 ORDER BY p.product_clicks DESC
 LIMIT 21
```

Why is it not grabbing the correct vendor name?  From my understanding the "LEFT OUTER JOIN vendors as v ON c.price_vendor = v.vendor_id" should match the records and that it should pull the name in that specific vendor record.  How ever it seems to be pulling random vendor_name entries, and its different every time I refresh.

Comment: can u post the table structure ?

Comment: You are using a pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` which is billed as giving unpredictable results exactly as you describe.  Read this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: I am trying to return 21 results... if I dont have the group by clause the query will only return 1 result.

Comment: Not suggesting you eliminate the use of `GROUP BY` ... just suggesting you use it in a way that won't cause it to return randomly chosen values from some columns.

Comment: And that is the part I dont understand as these advanced queries are new to me.

Comment: Took me over a week to figure this out.  It is not the group by clause at all.  This is caused by the aggregate functions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302472/mysql-group-by-and-max-returns-wrong-rows